# Header and footer for `scrbook` mimicking `memoir`

Tags: header-footer, memoir, books, scrbook

Consider this MWE.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

I am using `scrbook` class for my document. I want the header and footer as if I use `memoir` or `book` class:

1. Chapter's first page: page number at the center bottom
2. Even page: page number at the top left, chapter title at the top right
3. Odd page: page number at the top right, section title at the top left

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load package `scrlayer-scrpage` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle:

```
\usepackage[
  automark,
  markcase=upper
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  automark,
  markcase=upper
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```